# Is there any web browser component for C++ Builder 6 except IE?

Tags: c++builder, twebbrowser, c++builder-6

Hello is there any commercial or free web browser component to work with C++ Builder 6 except IE that is included ?

Comment: You don't say why you ask. If it is because the default IE you get is way to old then it might be good to know you can actually select which IE version you get by setting a registry setting http://superuser.com/questions/432154/how-can-i-change-settings-or-version-of-embedded-browser-in-windows7

Answer (score 1):

A related thread you could read is [How to embed a browser object, other than IE<n>, in a Delphi application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162718/how-to-embed-a-browser-object-other-than-ien-in-a-delphi-application)

but consider that:

- the last release of the Mozilla ActiveX project by Adam Lock was around Firefox 1.5, so the project is now seriously out of date;
- the Chromium Embedded Framework is very interesting but I don't think it can be adapted to C++Builder 6 (
  [fail to install chromium embedded on C++ Builder from Delphi files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18643146/fail-to-install-chromium-embedded-on-c-builder-from-delphi-files)).

  There are issues even with "modern" C++Builder (http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/issues/detail?id=7) but it can be done.

A good starting point, if you would like to take the *hard way*, is [Embedding Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Embedding_Mozilla) but it's a GNU project using GNU tools.

You could build the DLL via MinGW/MSYS and then getting access to the functions exposed by the relevant DLLs...

You could also try a different approach: transforming a target executable top-level window in a child window of own application via the [`SetParent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function (take a look at [Embed an application (exe file) into another exe file (mozEmbed like)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154560/embed-an-application-exe-file-into-another-exe-file-mozembed-like)).

Comment: +1 very good answer, I think it should be accepted.  Also, if future readers decide to go with IE, keep in mind that you aren't getting "the latest version" of IE with this control, and now that Microsoft Outlook stopped using it, it will probably never be updated/improved.  There really are no good options for displaying HTML in your own app these days :(